# Specific NodeJS in Jenkin pipeline

Tags: javascript, angular, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was trying to build a jenkin pipeline deployment one of my angular based project, but it's always picking global node version, even jenkin has multiple node installed and I choose one of them like below inside our pipeline stage

```
nodejs("NodeJS1100") { // label: NodeJS1100 already installed version
sh "npm -d install "
}
```

I tried it without luck, any idea how can we choose specific node into out pipeline from already installed version.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Just installed on 1 Nodejs version on Global tool configuration ?

Comment: You can give nvm a try. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. You can manager your node versions well with such a utility.

Comment: we can not install nvm on that, because its not controlled by us, @th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install multi nodejs version on Global Tool configuration.

[image]

Then you can define :

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   tools {
    nodejs 'nodejs_10.15.3'
   }
```

Comment: Yes, actually I want something like that but with scripted pipeline, I have resolve with my below answer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here we can do it with scripted pipeline with multiple version installed

```
    stage (‘Build’ {
        //...
    }
    stage (‘Test’) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Under the stage something like below

```
 withEnv(['PATH+NPM=$PATH:<Path of your NodeJS bin>']) {
           sh 'npm cache clean -f '
           sh 'npm install -d '
 }
```

Comment: can you share an example too?